# Netsuite Suitescript API - Searching Transaction records returns duplicates

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am attempting a basic search query of the 'transaction' records (I have also attempted this with 'salesorder' with similar results).  The query has no filters, and requests only the internalid as a search column, but for some reason the results include the same record multiple times... sometimes MANY times.

```
[
  {
    "internalid": "1984"
  },
  {
    "internalid": "1984"
  },
  {
    "internalid": "1984"
  },
  {
    "internalid": "1998"
  },
  {
    "internalid": "1998"
  },
  {
    "internalid": "1998"
  },
  {
    "internalid": "2490"
  },
  {
    "internalid": "2490"
  },
  {
    "internalid": "2573"
  },
  {
    "internalid": "2573"
  },
  {
    "internalid": "2491"
  },
```

Why would this happen?  Is there any way to get the query to only return each record once?

EDIT:  Adding code as requested

```
var filters = [];
var columns = [];
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid'));

var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction', null, filters, columns);   

return searchResults;
```

Comment: could you please post how you build and execute the search?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please add a filter,

> mainline is TRUE

If you are using saved search via code, please add additional filter

as `new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T')` or `['mainline', 'is', 'T']`

as the search result pull up the same internal id, multiple times for all line items

> EDIT: For the provided code example

```
var columns = [];
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid'));

var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction', null, ['mainline', 'is', 'T'], columns);   

return searchResults;
```

Comment: An explanation of *why* this happens: On Transaction searches, NetSuite will return one result for the transaction body itself, and additionally *one result for each line item* on that transaction. `mainline` is the filter that helps you control this. If you filter `mainline` as `'T'`, then NetSuite will only give you the result for the Transaction body. If you filter `mainline` as `'F'`, then NetSuite will only give you the results for the transaction lines, and not for the body. Be aware that some transaction columns will not be available in your results if you set `mainline` to `'T'`

Comment: just to add there are additional results for shipping as well when 'mainline is F'

Comment: @erictgrubaugh there has to be something additional to the 'NetSuite will return one result for the transaction body itself, and additionally one result for each line item on that transaction'. I have a transaction with 10 line items. And when I execute a search w/o this mainline filter specified it returns a result set of size 12 (1 for body, 10 for items, 1 for something else). **Where does the additional 1 come from I have no explanation**

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov The additional line might be a COGS line, a Tax line, or a Shipping line; you can use the `cogs`, `shipping`, and `taxline` boolean filters to figure out which it is.