# Duplicate Entries Saved Search NetSuities

Tags: netsuite

When doing a search I am getting duplicate invoices. So invoices can have both drop shipment and ship from factory. So I want to create a report that only shows the invoice for drop shipment and all other invoices if not drop shipped. So if one part is dropped ship show only that invoice and not the other invoice with the same invoice number. End result, the dropship invoice, and all other not dropped shipped, invoice can not be duplicate keep in mind a invoice can be both dropshipped and shipped from factory thus leading to double entries for these results. How do I go about ride of this duplication what must I add?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suitescript API - Transaction query returns the same records many times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443264/suitescript-api-transaction-query-returns-the-same-records-many-times)

Comment: See the answer in the duplicate; basically you need to use the mainline filter.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to do this only through the search entry rather than through the SuiteScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Criteria tab, select the filter named "Mainline". Set it to Yes if you only want one result for the transaction, or set it to No if you want one result for each line item on the transaction. Read the comments in the duplicate question for a more detailed explanation of how mainline works. It works the same in the UI and in SuiteScript.